# Why doesn't rle accept a factor as input?

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm having trouble passing this `rle` function on a `data.frame`. Function works great on another set:

```
fgroup <- aggregate(fevents2[,3:14], list(weeks = fevents2[, 1]), function(x) rle(x)$values)
```

Which yields the error:

```
Error in rle(x) : 'x' must be an atomic vector
```

Sample data:

```
> dput(fevents2[1:20,])
structure(list(weeks = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), A1M.Date = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2012-05-09", "2012-05-10", "2012-05-11",
"2012-05-14", "2012-05-15", "2012-05-17", "2012-05-18", "2012-05-21",
"2012-05-22", "2012-05-24", "2012-05-25", "2012-05-28", "2012-05-29",
"2012-05-30", "2012-05-31", "2012-06-04", "2012-06-05", "2012-06-07",
"2012-06-08", "2012-06-11", "2012-06-12", "2012-06-14", "2012-06-15",
"2012-06-18", "2012-06-19", "2012-06-21", "2012-06-22"), class = "factor"),
    vv = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 1L, 13L,
    13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 24L), .Label = c("C AA",
    "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV",
    "C VB", "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA",
    "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "nil"), class = "factor"),
    rv = structure(c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L,
    10L, 10L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 25L, 10L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 25L
    ), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR",
    "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB", "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ",
    "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB",
    "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"), ja = structure(c(12L,
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 25L, 25L,
    12L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ",
    "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB",
    "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G JR",
    "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"),
    aa = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 25L, 25L,
    25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), .Label = c("C AA",
    "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV",
    "C VB", "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA",
    "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"
    ), class = "factor"), bv = structure(c(25L, 11L, 11L, 11L,
    23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L,
    23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV",
    "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB", "C VR", "C VV",
    "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR",
    "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"),
    aj = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 9L,
    9L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 25L, 25L), .Label = c("C AA",
    "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV",
    "C VB", "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA",
    "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"
    ), class = "factor"), vb = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 25L, 25L,
    25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 2L,
    25L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV",
    "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB", "C VR", "C VV",
    "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR",
    "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"),
    rj = structure(c(5L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L,
    16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("C AA",
    "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB",
    "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JR", "G RJ",
    "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"),
    rr = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C AA",
    "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV",
    "C VB", "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA",
    "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"
    ), class = "factor"), vr = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 25L, 25L,
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 25L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,
    7L), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR",
    "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB", "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ",
    "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G JR", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB",
    "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"), bb = structure(c(4L,
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ", "C BB", "C BV",
    "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB", "C VR", "C VV",
    "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV",
    "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor"), jr = structure(c(25L,
    25L, 10L, 10L, 22L, 22L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L,
    25L, 25L, 25L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("C AA", "C AJ",
    "C BB", "C BV", "C JA", "C JR", "C RJ", "C RR", "C RV", "C VB",
    "C VR", "C VV", "G AA", "G AJ", "G BB", "G BV", "G JA", "G JR",
    "G RJ", "G RR", "G RV", "G VB", "G VR", "G VV", "nil"), class = "factor")),
.Names = c("weeks",
"A1M.Date", "vv", "rv", "ja", "aa", "bv", "aj", "vb", "rj", "rr",
"vr", "bb", "jr"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Structure of data:

```
str(fevents2)
data.frame':   1430 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ weeks   : Factor w/ 7 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ A1M.Date: Factor w/ 27 levels "2012-05-09","2012-05-10",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ vv      : Factor w/ 24 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 8 8 8 20 24 24 24 1 13 13 ..
 $ rv      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 10 10 ...
 $ ja      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ aa      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 25 25 ...
 $ bv      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 25 11 11 11 23 23 23 23 23 23 ...
 $ aj      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 7 7 7 25 25 25 25 25 9 9 ...
 $ vb      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 1 1 1 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 ...
 $ rj      : Factor w/ 23 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 5 5 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
 $ rr      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ vr      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 5 5 5 25 25 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ bb      : Factor w/ 24 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ jr      : Factor w/ 25 levels "C AA","C AJ",..: 25 25 10 10 22 22 25 25 25 25 ...
NULL
```

I understand that I have `factor`s, but converting `factor`s to `numeric` with

```
as.numeric(as.character(fevents2))
```

or:

```
sapply(fevents2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

doesn't solve my issue:

```
Error in fevents3[, 3:14] : incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Here's a sample `data.frame` on which the `rle` function works:

```
    dput(fevents[1:20,]
structure(list(weeks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), A1M.Date = c("2012-05-09", "2012-05-09",
"2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09",
"2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09",
"2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09",
"2012-05-09", "2012-05-09", "2012-05-09"), vv = c("C RR", "C RR",
"C RR", "G RR", "nil", "nil", "nil", "C AA", "G AA", "G AA",
"G AA", "G AA", "G AA", "G AA", "G AA", "G AA", "G AA", "G AA",
"G AA", "nil"), rv = c("nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil",
"nil", "nil", "C VB", "C VB", "G VB", "G VB", "G VB", "nil",
"G VB", "G VB", "G VB", "G VB", "G VB", "nil"), ja = c("C VV",
"C VV", "C VV", "C VV", "C VV", "C VV", "C VV", "C VV", "C VV",
"C VV", "C VV", "nil", "nil", "G VV", "G VV", "G VV", "G VV",
"G VV", "G VV", "G VV"), aa = c("C AJ", "C AJ", "C AJ", "C AJ",
"C AJ", "C AJ", "C AJ", "C AJ", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil",
"nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil"), bv = c("nil",
"C VR", "C VR", "C VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR",
"G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR", "G VR",
"G VR", "G VR", "G VR"), aj = c("C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "nil",
"nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "C RV", "C RV", "G RV", "G RV", "G RV",
"G RV", "G RV", "G RV", "G RV", "G RV", "nil", "nil"), vb = c("C AA",
"C AA", "C AA", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil",
"nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "C AJ", "nil", "C AJ",
"C AJ"), rj = c("C JR", "C JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR",
"G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR",
"G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR", "G JR"), rr = c("C BB",
"C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB",
"C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB", "C BB",
"C BB", "C BB", "C BB"), vr = c("C JA", "C JA", "C JA", "nil",
"nil", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "nil", "C RJ",
"C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ", "C RJ"
), bb = c("C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV",
"C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV",
"C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV", "C BV"), jr = c("nil", "nil",
"C VB", "C VB", "G VB", "G VB", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil",
"nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "nil", "C JA", "C JA", "C JA", "C JA"
)), .Names = c("weeks", "A1M.Date", "vv", "rv", "ja", "aa", "bv",
"aj", "vb", "rj", "rr", "vr", "bb", "jr"), row.names = c(NA,
20L), class = "data.frame")

str(fevents)
'data.frame':   1430 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ weeks   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ A1M.Date: chr  "2012-05-09" "2012-05-09" "2012-05-09" "2012-05-09" ...
 $ vv      : chr  "C RR" "C RR" "C RR" "G RR" ...
 $ rv      : chr  "nil" "nil" "nil" "nil" ...
 $ ja      : chr  "C VV" "C VV" "C VV" "C VV" ...
 $ aa      : chr  "C AJ" "C AJ" "C AJ" "C AJ" ...
 $ bv      : chr  "nil" "C VR" "C VR" "C VR" ...
 $ aj      : chr  "C RJ" "C RJ" "C RJ" "nil" ...
 $ vb      : chr  "C AA" "C AA" "C AA" "nil" ...
 $ rj      : chr  "C JR" "C JR" "G JR" "G JR" ...
 $ rr      : chr  "C BB" "C BB" "C BB" "C BB" ...
 $ vr      : chr  "C JA" "C JA" "C JA" "nil" ...
 $ bb      : chr  "C BV" "C BV" "C BV" "C BV" ...
 $ jr      : chr  "nil" "nil" "C VB" "C VB" ...
```

I found a really "not elegant" workaround. Writing `data.frame` to file as CSV and importing it with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. This is not what I want to write in my code... There must be a simpler way to rearrange the structure of the `data.frame` to please `rle`?

Comment: Can you replace the output of `str(fevents)` with the output of `dput(fevents[1:20, ])` That way we can copy your text directly into R & work with your data.

Comment: Question edited to give sample

Comment: Are `fevents` and `fevents2` the same thing? EDIT: I see your edit now, never mind.

Comment: no, fevents is the data.frame on which rle function works. fevents2 is the data.frame with factors. I edited my question so it's should be clearer

Comment: I'll put a sample of the non working data.frame to with dput

Comment: Test: replace `rle(x)` in your `aggregate...` with, say, `typeof(x)` or `dim(x)`  to see just what you are passing to `rle` .

Comment: @ Carl : typeof(x) gives me : integrer and dim(x) : NULL

Comment: @Chargaff you know the problem, `rle` doesn't take factors. Your attempts to 'convert' the `data.frame` to `character` aren't doing what you think. Aggregate over this instead: `fevents.subset <- as.data.frame(apply(fevents2[,3:14], 2, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: @Chargraff You could also just replace `rle(x)$values` with `rle(as.numeric(x))$values` or `rle(as.character(x))$values`, whatever suits your needs.

Comment: @mplourde One of the common errors is `as.numeric(some_factor)`  FAQ makes it clear that you need to do `as.numeric(as.character(some_factor))` .

Comment: @Carl Yes, FAQ makes it clear, but in my case, I clearly needed to rle(as.character(x))$value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that a factor *is* *not* an atomic vector as the error clearly says. Either convert all the factors to characters first (and not by coercing them to numeric!) or do the conversion *inside* the anonymous function you are applying.

So this, which implements the second idea, works:

```
aggregate(fevents2[,3:14], list(weeks = fevents2[, 1]),
          function(x) rle(as.character(x))$values)
```

after a fashion:

```
> aggregate(fevents2[,3:14], list(weeks = fevents2[, 1]),
+           function(x) rle(as.character(x))$values)
  weeks vv.1 vv.2 vv.3 vv.4 vv.5 vv.6 rv.1 rv.2 rv.3 rv.4 rv.5 rv.6 rv.7 ja.1
1     1 C RR G RR  nil C AA G AA  nil  nil C VB G VB  nil C VB G VB  nil C VV
  ja.2 ja.3 ja.4 aa.1 aa.2 bv.1 bv.2 bv.3 aj.1 aj.2 aj.3 aj.4 aj.5 vb.1 vb.2
1  nil C VV G VV C AJ  nil  nil C VR G VR C RJ  nil C RV G RV  nil C AA  nil
  vb.3 vb.4 vb.5 rj.1 rj.2   rr vr.1 vr.2 vr.3 vr.4 vr.5   bb jr.1 jr.2 jr.3
1 C AJ  nil C AJ C JR G JR C BB C JA  nil C RJ  nil C RJ C BV  nil C VB G VB
  jr.4 jr.5
1  nil C JA
```

though I am not sure what you expected to get - there is only one week here and `aggregate` and `rle` have stuck all the values together. Did you want separate `$values` for each of the variables in `fevents2` that you are aggregating over?

Another thing:

`as.numeric(as.character(fevents2))` can't *possibly* work as the data are not numeric! and you can't apply those functions to a data frame and get anything like what you intended - if they work at all.

The `sapply()` thing should work. Here is a version that checks whether each variable is a factor or not and coerces it if it is:

```
fevents3 <- sapply(fevents2,
                   function(x) if(is.factor(x)) { as.character(x) } else { x })
```

But note `sapply()` simplifies to a matrix which will change the `aggregate()` method dispatched:

```
> class(fevents3)
[1] "matrix"
```

Instead perhaps

```
fevents3 <- lapply(fevents2,
                   function(x) if(is.factor(x)) { as.character(x) } else { x })
fevents3 <- data.frame(fevents3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now if you wanted to *apply* `rle()` to each column of the split-up data and keep the separate how about

```
spl <- split(fevents3, list(weeks = fevents3[, 1]))
res <- lapply(spl, function(x) lapply(x[, 3:14], function(y) rle(y)$values))
```

which gives

```
> res
$`1`
$`1`$vv
[1] "C RR" "G RR" "nil"  "C AA" "G AA" "nil" 

$`1`$rv
[1] "nil"  "C VB" "G VB" "nil"  "C VB" "G VB" "nil" 

$`1`$ja
[1] "C VV" "nil"  "C VV" "G VV"

$`1`$aa
[1] "C AJ" "nil" 

$`1`$bv
[1] "nil"  "C VR" "G VR"

$`1`$aj
[1] "C RJ" "nil"  "C RV" "G RV" "nil" 

$`1`$vb
[1] "C AA" "nil"  "C AJ" "nil"  "C AJ"

$`1`$rj
[1] "C JR" "G JR"

$`1`$rr
[1] "C BB"

$`1`$vr
[1] "C JA" "nil"  "C RJ" "nil"  "C RJ"

$`1`$bb
[1] "C BV"

$`1`$jr
[1] "nil"  "C VB" "G VB" "nil"  "C JA"
```

Which is the same answer as that for `aggregate()` above, but with each `rle()` output kept separate:

```
> unlist(res)
 1.vv1  1.vv2  1.vv3  1.vv4  1.vv5  1.vv6  1.rv1  1.rv2  1.rv3  1.rv4  1.rv5 
"C RR" "G RR"  "nil" "C AA" "G AA"  "nil"  "nil" "C VB" "G VB"  "nil" "C VB" 
 1.rv6  1.rv7  1.ja1  1.ja2  1.ja3  1.ja4  1.aa1  1.aa2  1.bv1  1.bv2  1.bv3 
"G VB"  "nil" "C VV"  "nil" "C VV" "G VV" "C AJ"  "nil"  "nil" "C VR" "G VR" 
 1.aj1  1.aj2  1.aj3  1.aj4  1.aj5  1.vb1  1.vb2  1.vb3  1.vb4  1.vb5  1.rj1 
"C RJ"  "nil" "C RV" "G RV"  "nil" "C AA"  "nil" "C AJ"  "nil" "C AJ" "C JR" 
 1.rj2   1.rr  1.vr1  1.vr2  1.vr3  1.vr4  1.vr5   1.bb  1.jr1  1.jr2  1.jr3 
"G JR" "C BB" "C JA"  "nil" "C RJ"  "nil" "C RJ" "C BV"  "nil" "C VB" "G VB" 
 1.jr4  1.jr5 
 "nil" "C JA" 
> aggregate(fevents2[,3:14], list(weeks = fevents2[, 1]),
+           function(x) rle(as.character(x))$values)
  weeks vv.1 vv.2 vv.3 vv.4 vv.5 vv.6 rv.1 rv.2 rv.3 rv.4 rv.5 rv.6 rv.7 ja.1
1     1 C RR G RR  nil C AA G AA  nil  nil C VB G VB  nil C VB G VB  nil C VV
  ja.2 ja.3 ja.4 aa.1 aa.2 bv.1 bv.2 bv.3 aj.1 aj.2 aj.3 aj.4 aj.5 vb.1 vb.2
1  nil C VV G VV C AJ  nil  nil C VR G VR C RJ  nil C RV G RV  nil C AA  nil
  vb.3 vb.4 vb.5 rj.1 rj.2   rr vr.1 vr.2 vr.3 vr.4 vr.5   bb jr.1 jr.2 jr.3
1 C AJ  nil C AJ C JR G JR C BB C JA  nil C RJ  nil C RJ C BV  nil C VB G VB
  jr.4 jr.5
1  nil C JA
```

[*Note:* This is only true here because the data snippet you show has just one week. I can't recall how `unlist(res))` will look if there is more than one week.]

Comment: Yes,aggregate(fevents2[,3:14], list(weeks = fevents2[, 1]),function(x) rle(as.character(x))$values) works great. I have several weeks and aggregate datas works as expected. Thanks for the explanation, this problem was giving me headaches !

Comment: _"a factor is *not* an atomic vector"_ For those (also) confused, while a `factor` is indeed `atomic` (`is.atomic(iris$Species)  ##TRUE`), it is NOT a `vector` (`is.vector(iris$Species)  ##FALSE`). Live and learn.

Comment: @landroni don't take at face value what those `is.` functions are saying. The R Language Definition for the current release [says](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects) "R has six basic (‘atomic’) vector types: logical, integer, real, complex, string (or character) and raw." Note factor is not among them as it is more complex object based on an integer vector. `is.vector()` is testing for something more than just being a vector. The behaviour is explained in `?is.atomic` and `?is.vector`.

Comment: @landroni The reason `is.atomic()` returns true for factors is, I believe, because they are (if you strip away the levels) stored as an integer type and that type *is* considered atomic: `typeof(iris$Species)`. `is.vector()` returns `FALSE` for a factor because, as documented, that function will only accept as vectors those that have no attributes but `names`. If you look at `attributes(iris$Species)` you'll see other attributes, hence the `FALSE` from `is.vector(iris$Species)`. Hope this clears it up a little?