# Count number of sequences of a specific value per group

Tags: r, count, sequence

Lets say I have a data frame with an ID and a variable in which the response is either ON or OFF.
I want to count the number of runs of "ON" per group. I had nearly managed this but realised my solution wasn't working on the first or last value in the group depending on whether I was trying to use lead or lag.

I have searched SO and can find similar problems but non seem to match this exactly.

```
id <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b","c", "c","c","c","c","c","c","c" )
category <- c("ON", "OFF", "OFF", "ON", "ON", "ON", "OFF", "OFF", "ON", "ON", "OFF", "OFF","OFF","OFF","OFF", "ON", "ON","ON")
dat<-data.frame(id, category)
```

My attempt so far which is not working I think because it doesn't work if the run starts as "ON" in a group

```
summary(dat %>% group_by(id)%>% filter(category == "ON", lead(category!="ON"))%>% count(category) %>% arrange(n))
```

Very grateful for any assistance. My actual dataset is 40,000 rows with 120 id's and in each id the category may start as either ON or OFF

Output would be something like this:

```
# id    category       n    
# a:1   OFF:0    Min.   :1  
# b:1   ON :2    1st Qu.:1  
# c:0            Median :1  
#                Mean   :1  
#                3rd Qu.:1  
#                Max.   :1
```

So that the interpretation would be 2 id's has a run of "ON" at any point and the median number of runs of ON (in this tiny sample) was 1

Comment: I'm not quite sure about what your desired output should be, but maybe something like `rle(category)` (with `rle()` being a `base` function) could be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# step 1
out <- dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  nest()

# outcome step 1
out
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   id [3]
#   id    data            
#   <chr> <list>          
# 1 a     <tibble [5 x 1]>
# 2 b     <tibble [5 x 1]>
# 3 c     <tibble [8 x 1]>

# step 2
out <- out %>%
  mutate(run = map(data, ~ {
    out_map <- rle(.x$category)
    out_map <- tibble(length = out_map[[1]], category = out_map[[2]])
    return(out_map)
  })) %>%
  select(-data)

# outcome step 2
out
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   id [3]
#   id    run             
#   <chr> <list>          
# 1 a     <tibble [3 x 2]>
# 2 b     <tibble [3 x 2]>
# 3 c     <tibble [2 x 2]>

# step 3
out <- out %>%
  unnest(cols = c(run)) %>%
  # this line lets you filter for category and the minimum line of the run
  filter(category == "ON", length > 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as_factor)
    
out
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id    length category
#   <fct>  <int> <fct>   
# 1 a          2 ON      
# 2 b          2 ON      
# 3 c          3 ON      

count(out, id, category, sort = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id    category     n
#   <fct> <fct>    <int>
# 1 a     ON           1
# 2 b     ON           1
# 3 c     ON           1

summary(out)
#  id        length      category
#  a:1   Min.   :2.000   ON:3    
#  b:1   1st Qu.:2.000           
#  c:1   Median :2.000           
#        Mean   :2.333           
#        3rd Qu.:2.500           
#        Max.   :3.000
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm struggling to follow your second answer a little, forgive my ignorance. The first answer I think I understood but it appeared to be double counting when I checked it on the real data

Comment: The first part (up to the comment) gives you a list of all category-runs by id in the data. You can then filter these runs by category (e.g. only category "ON") and by length of the run (e.g. > 1). Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh thanks. As it runs on the sample data, I get an error:
Error in rle(.x$category) : 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type.
I'm guessing you didn't get this so not sure why I am?

Comment: Hmm.. I've just simulated your dataset with more ids, but no error. Probably add `print(.x)` before as first line of the `map` command to see at which subset you get the error and how this subset looks like.

Comment: Still struggling with this I'm afraid, did you implement exactly as written? Is there any way of doing this with a dplyr solution?

Comment: Does the code run at all or do you get the error only for certain ids?

I have broken up the code in three steps, so that we can check your outcomes for each step. Is the result of `step 1` a dataframe with a list of tibbles in the `data` column? Does each of these nested tibbles have a column `category`?

If your `step 1` output looks like mine, run `step 2` manually by assigning `.x` by hand. Try this for different ids (i.e. different parts of the `out$data` list) and check if it works.

Comment: Thankyou for this help! Step 1 works fine. When I run out_map<- rle(.x$category) on either 1st, 2nd or 3rd row I get the error: 'x' must be a vector of an atomic type

Comment: At least we can exclude one issue :-) Does your variable `.x` look like mine (I've just added my variable output to the code)?

Comment: Could it be that the variable `category` is coded as a factor when it is passed to `rle` in `step 2`? This issue is desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311457/why-doesnt-rle-accept-a-factor-as-input) and let reproduce your error message.

Comment: Yes! Ah silly of me. That works.
However If I then pass that to step 3: Error in map_lgl(.x, .p, ...) : object 'run' not found

Comment: That's my bad! When I edited the code I mixed variable names up. The last line of the function within `map` should say `return(out_map)`.

Comment: OK brilliant. I've got it all working in the test. Its nearly working in the real data! I've cut the real data table down to just the ID and the category. Its working down to the end of step 2. When I check out$run I can see all the tibbles and the lengths of all the 'ON' and 'OFF's. The third step is failing as it is saying result must have length 7, not 18. 
Would this be because some tibbles don't have any 'ON's at all or something? In the real data even a single 'ON' counts for my purposes. Anything you can suggest without seeing the real data??

Comment: Does your output from `step 2` look like mine (just edited my answer)? It's important that all tibbles of `out$run` have the same number of columns. The number of rows don't matter.

Comment: Its all working. Thankyou SO much for your help. I've run the whole data set through it (34000 rows, 115 Id's). I had a comparison method for median ON per ID and initially this was much less and I couldn't work out why. Then I realised the median I was  looking at in the output from your method was the median of all the runs not grouped to an ID. So I added summary(out %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(length), n = n())) to get both the median of the total ON per ID and the median number of 'episodes' of ON (hope you would think this is the right thing to do?).

Comment: Also changed length to >=1 as I am counting any ON at all.
Thankyou!!!!

Comment: Glad that I could help you! The problem already started getting personal :D Could you please accept the answer to indicate that it solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

in `base-R` we can use

```
tapply(dat$category, dat$id, function(x) with(rle(as.character(x)),sum(values == "ON")))

a b c 
2 2 1
```